# Quitting a job without having another job offer

Tags: new-job, job-change, resignation, india

I am PHP developer and I am currently working in tech startup in India. I have 3.5 years of experience in PHP development.

Currently my company's financial situation is not good so they start working on sort out the employees count(the good thing is i am not in the list).

I plan to quit my job but unfortunately I don't have any job offers in my hand. Is is good idea to quit the job immediately or not ? Please give your thoughts on this.

Comment: How many days for notice period in your company?

Comment: Why quit a job when you do not have one to go to?

Comment: 90 days @gunaseelan

Comment: I am not satisfied with current one @Ed heal

Comment: Be that as it may. What will you do for money in the meantime? Just hang in there and look hard for alternative employment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is is good idea to quit the job immediately or not ?

In my opinion, it's a bad idea to quit a job without having another job ready.

- The financial pressure of being unemployed can lead you to make decisions you wouldn't otherwise make. You might need to take a less-than-optimal job just to be able to pay the bills. That can lead to job hopping.
- Many employers view quitting a job without another waiting as a sign that work isn't that important to you. Companies like to hire people who treat work as important.
- Sometimes, market conditions turn sour and you could end up unemployed far longer than anticipated. For right or wrong, employers would rather hire someone who already has a job than someone who is unemployed - particularly when the economy is bad and many people are applying for one job. (I'm not saying this is a good thing, just that it happens.)

The counter to all that might be that you could be offered an attractive severance package if you offer to be part of the group being laid off at your company. But that's hard to know for sure, and a risky move.

In general, I have found that you would be far better served by finding your next job, getting an offer and formal acceptance, then handing in your resignation and working out your notice period.

Comment: It should be noted that the notice period may be up for negotiation. That has been my experience in the past,. People tend to be reasonable

Comment: If you do not ask you do  not get. My Victorian ancestors have a lot to answer for - including that bad project over the Atlantic! It was never meant to end this way!!

Comment: If the company is looking to reduce staff due to a poor financial situation, they may be more likely to negotiate on notice period.